# Using django-smart-selects, Empty ChainedForeignKey In Admin When Editing

Tags: django

I'm using django-smart-selects in django project. I'm using ChainedForeignKey in 'Country'. when adding new record, it works fine: selected 'Continent' then Chained 'Country' appeared. 
BUT while editing this record, 'Country' shows empty value.

Any idea for this?